# Content not respecting parent height with flex: vertical;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an element inside of a flex-box. If the flex-box is horizontal, the element inside expands horizontally to fill the flex-box. If the flex-box is vertical, the element does not expand vertically to fill the flex-box.

I found some other StackOverflow posts which discuss the issue, but the solutions revolve around making all children flexible which allows them to fill 100% height. I am looking for a solution which allows the children to fill any-percent height.

The easiest fix for this is to apply `.flex-vertical .flex-child { height: 100% }` and then everything works as expected, **but I would like to understand why setting height is necessary when it is not needed for width.**

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29xba61e/11/)

and here's the accompanying code:

```
<div class='flex flex-vertical'>
    <div class='flex-child'>
        <div class='line'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class='flex flex-horizontal'>
    <div class='flex-child'>
        <div class='line'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class='flex flex-vertical'>
    <div class='flex-child fixed'>
        <div class='line'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.flex-vertical {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: green;
}

.flex-horizontal {
    background-color: orange;
}

.flex-child {
    flex: 1;
}

.line {
    background-color: blue;
}

.flex-vertical .line {
    width: 5px;
    height: 66%;
}

.flex-horizontal .line {
    height: 5px;
    width: 66%;
}

.fixed {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Please note that I'm working inside the latest version of Google Chrome and I am only targeting the latest version of Google Chrome with my CSS. I am aware there may be vendor prefix differences or varying implementations in other browsers, but I am only curious about Google Chrome.

Comment: `the element does not expand vertically to fill the flex-box.` Actually it *does*! the element you've named `flex-child` which is the flex item technically, fills the whole flex container by adding `flex: 1` declaration as you've done it yourself! Note the `lime` colored area http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/29xba61e/13/

Comment: And also as a side-note, there's no `flex: vertical;` declaration.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. The first and second boxes both contain very similar code except for the fact that one has flexible columns and the other has flexible rows. The first box does not show its blue line, but the second box does. Adding height: 100% resolves the issue, shown on the third box, but I was curious why it is needed.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but you should note that that blue line in not a flex item to take the height of its parent - the flex container - Besides, you have specified the `height` property with a percentage value `height: 66%;` which is relative to the height of its containing block - i.e the height of the flex item - And since the flex item has no explicit `height` value, any percentage value of `height` is calculated to `0`.

Comment: Why is the same not true for horizontal, though? I have not explicitly set a width.

Comment: Sean, you are right. I just checked the computed styles of the flex items on Chrome37, technically the percentage height should work when the flex direction is set to `column`, however it seems it doesn't. That's weird because the computed value of `display` is `block` and the `height` is `200px` in this case.

Comment: We're in agreement! I'm glad I'm not going crazy... I'll try to find some time to dig through Chrome's bug tracker in a bit and see if this is mentioned anywhere. Thanks!